# Not able to extend root partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have dual boot system with ubuntu 17 and windows 10. Initially I had allocated 30Gb space for ubuntu(sda4), but now I want to increase this space. I tried this through Gparted in live usb ubuntu, but it is not allowing me to extend sda4 partition. I have 20Gb of free space just after sda4 partition. How to do this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S16Zi.png

Comment: You have to do it from a LiveCD, You can't modify a mounted partition

Comment: @ravery Since the screenshot doesn't show a mounted root, I assume OP *is* using a live cd/usb.

Comment: @wjandrea -- swap and sda4 are both mounted.

Comment: @ravery Yes, swap gets mounted automatically by a live system.

Comment: i am alread using live usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the swap partition (/dev/sda5), then click "Swapoff". Then it should work.

**More details**: When you start a live system, it automatically uses the swap partition. While the swap partition is in use, it and its containing extended partition cannot be modified. So when you tell the live system to stop using the swap, it and the extended partition should become modifiable.